# Ext JS 3.4.0 TreeNode - same icon for all nodes

Tags: javascript, extjs3, treenode, treepanel

I have a TreePanel in Ext JS 3.4.0. The nodes are loaded via JSON.

First of all I need to have the same icons for all the nodes, no matter if they are leafs or not. So I don't want to have the "folder" icon for the nodes that have children. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you set in JSON for all node    .iconCls   property to the same value,  all nodes will have same icon

For example:

```
"iconCls": "icon-file",
"expanded": "true",
"children": [
   {
        "iconCls": "icon-file",
        "leaf": "true"
   }
```

Icon-file is the a css with icon you want, for example:

```
.icon-file
{
   background-image: url(../images/silk/grid.png) !important;
}
```